# VS Code Jupyter extension running multiple R sessions, hogging up memory

Tags: ubuntu, memory, visual-studio-code, r, jupyter-notebook

As the heading states, I'm running R in the Jupyter notebook inside VS Code (on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS).

What I've noticed, is that VS Code or the Jupyter extension initiates multiple R sessions as seen in my system monitor (below). In addition, VS Code runs multiple sessions as well.
This (R in particular) occupies a lot of my computer's available memory. Currently, it occupies ~26 GB, with no processes running. I have no objects in my workspace that would warrant such an enormous memory hog. The buildup seems to occur when I run demanding computations/processes, and R is, seemingly, unable to free up the memory after. I tried running `gc()` and empty unused variables in my workspace, but to no avail. I think this has to something to do with how the Jupyter extension initiates multiple R sessions.

I am trying to understand why this happens, and if there's a way to get VS Code/Jupyter to terminate processes and release memory that is not really in use?

[image]

[image]

---

###### Edit (2022-04-19)

This issue has been [tracked as bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9700) on the extensions GitHub pages.